# Google isn't indexing all the Pages in my Site

Tags: indexing, search-engine

In my [website](http://laterrassemykonos.gr) i use jquery to dynamically change the primary contents of a div(my primary content) so that pages are not reloading when someone presses a link but it adds content to the div.

Google searches for links in my site and finds only #smth and it does not index the pages.What should i do so that Google will index my other pages?

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: true sorry i just changed that

Comment: I'm voting for closing this question as off-topic. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on the network site Pro Webmasters at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You can add a sitemap.xml file using the Sitemaps protocol to the root of your website (or another location specified in robots.txt). The Sitemaps protocol allows you to inform search engines about URLs on a website that are available for crawling ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps)).

An example sitemap (from referenced [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) above) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2006-11-18</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

The crawler of a search engine will visit your sitemap.xml and index the locations specified.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the answer is to add ! in front of your hash urls and configure the server to send a snapshot of the page to google more info [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)

Comment: Seems like the best solution.